# Php bin2hex Parse Error

Tags: php

I dont understand why this keeps throwing a "PHP Parse error":

```
$salt = bin2hex(mcrypt_create_iv(size)(32, MCRYPT_DEV_URANDOM));
```

Any ideas?

Comment: Because you have twice as many groups of parenthesis as necessary?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because

```
mcrypt_create_iv(size)(32, MCRYPT_DEV_URANDOM)
```

is nonsense. Should be

```
mcrypt_create_iv(32, MCRYPT_DEV_URANDOM)
```